# Get specific value from table

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a script that gets an email address from a .msg file and I have gotten most of the script to work the way I want it.

So for this string:

```
(Select-String -InputObject $SEMFINAL -Pattern '\w+@\w+\.\w+' -AllMatches).Matches
```

I get:

```
Index    : 0
Length   : 15
Value    : email@email.com
```

How can I filter the results to only get the data for the Value in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the most graceful solution, but would this work?:

```psh
$SEMFINAL = "Hello my address is bob@example.com Thanks. P.S. You can also reach me at robert@example.com" 
(Select-String -InputObject $SEMFINAL -Pattern '\w+@\w+\.\w+' -AllMatches).matches | select value
```

Output (`Value` property of the match objects):

```
Value
-----
bob@example.com
robert@example.com
```

To expand the properties to their actual value, change the last portion to

```psh
| select -Expand value
```

to the end.

```psh
(Select-String -InputObject $SEMFINAL -Pattern '\w+@\w+\.\w+' -AllMatches).matches | select -Expand value
```

Output:

```
bob@example.com
Robert@example.com
```

Comment: I think that is the closest I will get to it. Ideally would be good if you could remove the Value and - - - -

Comment: That's just Powershell formatting the Object.
How about this:
adding
   " | foreach {$_.value}" 
to the end

Comment: whats the "adding" in the first part

Comment: I edited my answer to show the full command. What I mean by "adding" is to take the existing command and write the quoted portion onto the end of it. Sorry for the ambiguous formatting.

Comment: Use `select -Expand Value` to get just the value instead of an object with only the `Value` property.

Comment: I think Ansgar's solution is a better option for what you're trying to accomplish, I'd go with that.

Comment: @WilliamNelson It's just a slightly more elegant way to get to the value. Update your answer with it if you like.

Comment: If the OP has at least PowerShell 3.0 so you should just be able to `(Select-String -..... -AllMatches).matches.value`

Answer (score 0):

I just recently learned about objects and hash tables, which I think is what is going on here. You need to create an object with the values you want assigned to it. Otherwise it will only give you the length of the values.

So something like:

```
 $EmailInput = (Select-String -InputObject $SEMFINAL -Pattern '\w+@\w+\.\w+' -AllMatches).Matches
 $Email = @{
            "Email" = $EmailInput
        }
        $EmailObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Email
```

I'm still learning, so you may need to mess with it a bit (or a lot), but I think you'll need to put that info into an object if you want to read the actual values instead of just lengths.

If someone else understands objects better please correct me.